# Trying to deploy Azure Keyvault via Biceps - Firewall Bypass by Azure Services required?

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-bicep

I am using the following bicep template to deploy a key vault. Regarding the network configuration I want the firewall to allow connection from a subnet a specific IP range.

```
resource kv 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults@2023-07-01' = {
  name: vaultName
  location: location
  properties: {
    tenantId: subscription().tenantId
    enableRbacAuthorization: true
    publicNetworkAccess: null
    enabledForDeployment: false
    enabledForDiskEncryption: false
    enabledForTemplateDeployment: false
    enableSoftDelete: true
    softDeleteRetentionInDays: 30
    sku: {
      name: 'standard'
      family: 'A'
    }
    networkAcls: {
      defaultAction: 'Deny'
      bypass: 'None'
      ipRules: [for ip in allowIps: { value:ip }]
      virtualNetworkRules: [
        {
          id: allowSubnet
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

resource key 'Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/keys@2023-07-01' = {
  parent: kv
  name: guid(vaultName, 'ssh-key')
  properties: {
    keySize: 4096
    keyOps: [
      'encrypt'
      'decrypt'
    ]
    kty: 'RSA'
    rotationPolicy: {
      lifetimeActions: [
        {
          trigger: {
            timeBeforeExpiry: 'P30D'
          }
          action: {
            type: 'notify'
          }
        }
        {
          trigger: {
            timeBeforeExpiry: 'P7D'
          }
          action: {
            type: 'rotate'
          }
        }
      ]
      attributes: {
        expiryTime: 'P1Y10D'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When I deploy this I get an error message. I have redacted the vault name and my user principal id. The remaining app id is meant to be the [Azure Powershell Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/troubleshoot/azure/active-directory/verify-first-party-apps-sign-in#:%7E:text=1950a258%2D227b%2D4e31%2Da9cf%2D717495945fc2) which I use for deployment. The IP address `20.61.103.227` belongs to an Azure data center in the NL (westeurope region) where our infra resides.

```
The deployment 'main' failed with error(s). Showing 2 out of 2 error(s). Status Message: [ForbiddenByFirewall (Forbidden)] Request was not allowed by
     | NSP rules and the client address is not authorized and caller was ignored because bypass is set to None Client address: 20.61.103.227 Caller:
     | name=KeyVault/ManagementPlane;appid=1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2;oid=<MY_USER_PRINCIPAL_ID> Vault:
     | <MY_KEY_VAULT_NAME>;location=westeurope (Code:ForbiddenByFirewall)  Status Message: At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list
     | deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details. (Code: DeploymentFailed)  - [ForbiddenByFirewall
     | (Forbidden)] Request was not allowed by NSP rules and the client address is not authorized and caller was ignored because bypass is set to None Client address:
     | 20.61.103.227 Caller: name=KeyVault/ManagementPlane;appid=1950a258-227b-4e31-a9cf-717495945fc2;oid=<MY_USER_PRINCIPAL_ID> Vault:
     | <MY_KEY_VAULT_NAME>;location=westeurope (Code:ForbiddenByFirewall)   CorrelationId: 9e157b78-937a-4fd3-861c-3617c62efcc7
```

If in the vault template I set `bypass: 'AzureServices'` it works. Still, this effectively means letting trusted Azure Services bypass your vault firewall is no longer optional if I want an error-free deployment. What are your thoughts on this? Do you find this acceptable?

Also, I am VPN connected to the whitelisted IP range. I don't know why this does not suffice.

Any thoughts on this would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some information regarding [trusted services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/general/network-security?WT.mc_id=Portal-Microsoft_Azure_KeyVault#key-vault-firewall-enabled-trusted-services-only):

> When you enable the Key Vault Firewall, you'll be given an option to 'Allow Trusted Microsoft Services to bypass this firewall.' The trusted services list does not cover every single Azure service. For example, Azure DevOps isn't on the trusted services list. **This does not imply that services that do not appear on the trusted services list are not trusted or are insecure**. The trusted services list encompasses services where Microsoft controls all of the code that runs on the service. Since users can write custom code in Azure services such as Azure DevOps, Microsoft does not provide the option to create a blanket approval for the service. Furthermore, just because a service appears on the trusted service list, doesn't mean it is allowed for all scenarios.

You can find the list of trusted services [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/key-vault/general/overview-vnet-service-endpoints#trusted-services)

You are allowing **Azure Resource Manager template deployment service**: Pass secure values during deployment.

If you decide to keep it as is you would need to run the deployment from an authorized subnet or ip.

At the end, it is up to you based on your security requirements.

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your feedback. Despite the fact that I am deploying from an authorized/whitelisted IP, I'm still getting that error.

Comment: So you confirm that your IP is added in the ipRules?

Comment: If you try to create a key vault key using az cli from your device, does it work ?

Comment: Hi Thomas, yes to the 1st. The other I will check in a bit when I'm at my desk

Comment: And no, with `bypass: 'None'` the vault deploys fine, but the key does not. It seems by design after some more thought. My bicep deployment communicates with the ARM, which in turn communicates with the resource. The IP rules for the key vault are with respect to the data-plane, not the management-plane. Which explains why I am able to dpleoy the vault, but not the key. The key is in the data-plane. And the ARM Ips are not whitelisted. But since ARM is a trusted service, settings `bypass: 'AzureServices'` solves the problem.

Comment: Yeah make sense, Feel free to post an answer :-)